# Finding $A^n$ in terms of $P$ and $D$ (diagonalized)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

My question is regarding the last two parts. I have Found $D$ and $P$, how can I obtain $A^{200}$ and det $(A^{200})$ form $PDP^{-1}?$ Thanks! [image]

Answer (score 2):

Finding $A^{n}$ of a diagonal matrix is actually pretty trivial, but I'll show you why (don't worry, I was confused when I first did this).

$$A=PDP^{-1}$$
$$A^{n}=(PDP^{-1})^{n}$$
$$=PDP^{-1}PDP^{-1}PDP^{-1}...$$
Obviously $PP^{-1}=I$, because they are inverses of one another.  We can keep doing this as many times and we end up with...
$$A^{n}=PD^{n}P^{-1}$$
Now this is easy because $D$ is a diagonal matrix and $D^{n}$ is just the matrix composed of $D_{ij}^{n}$, where $D_{ii}$ is the $ii^{th}$ entry of of D.  Finding the determinant is also easy.
$$det(A^{n})=det(PD^{n}P^{-1})$$
$$=det(P)det(D^{n})det(P^{-1})$$
$$=det(P)\frac{1}{det(P)}det(D^{n})$$
$$det(A^{n})=det(D^{n})$$
We are able to do step 2 and three because determinants are numbers and thus can commute, and three because of the inverse property.